# Scrapy Settings with ENV SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to split my settings in to `production.py` and `local.py`. Different settings are loaded in different environments, which I define in the ENV variable `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` as `project.local` or `project.production`.

Problem is, whenever I define the ENV var and run `scrapy crawl myspider` I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

If I don't define `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE`, then it is set to its default which is `project.settings`, and it throws no error. If I set the ENV var to its default value, I still get `ModuleNotFoundError` above.

So basically, it can import `project.settings` which is its default value, but if I set `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings` then it throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding your project to the PYTHONPATH. By looking at the code for loading the settings, you see that if you don't set the `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your ENV, `init_env` is called:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/bca374d65192e6347f847e0feeac5b8a2a84e710/scrapy/utils/project.py#L61-L63

Which sets up the `sys.path` for you appropriately:

https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/bca374d65192e6347f847e0feeac5b8a2a84e710/scrapy/utils/conf.py#L82